pdf viewer Blazor bootstrap
I'm trying to implement the blazor bootstrap pdf viewer,
but when I copy and paste the example code the document does not display.
it's really weird because you can even see that you never get the OnDocumentLoaded event
any idea? do i need to do something extra?

could you share what code you have added to your project to view the pdf file. are you getting any error? have you check your console to get more details

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You could try below working sample code to load the pdf in blazor server using Blazor.Bootstrap:
Download and install "Blazor.Bootstrap" nugget package
_Host.cshtml:
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@namespace BlazorPdfViewerDemo.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="BlazorPdfViewerDemo.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="_content/Blazor.Bootstrap/blazor.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</head>
<body>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Include Bootstrap's bundle -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="_content/Blazor.Bootstrap/blazor.bootstrap.pdf.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/Blazor.Bootstrap/blazor.bootstrap.js"></script>

</body>
</html>

CustomPdfViewer.razor:
 @page "/pdfviewer"

   @using BlazorBootstrap

<h3>PDF Viewer</h3>

<PdfViewer Class="mb-3"
           Url="pdf/sample.pdf"
           OnDocumentLoaded="OnDocumentLoaded"
           OnPageChanged="OnPageChanged" />

@code {
    private string eventLog { get; set; } = $"Last event: ..., CurrentPage: 0, TotalPages: 0";

    private void OnDocumentLoaded(PdfViewerEventArgs args)
        => eventLog = $"Last event: OnDocumentLoaded, CurrentPage: {args.CurrentPage}, TotalPages: {args.TotalPages}";

    private void OnPageChanged(PdfViewerEventArgs args)
        => eventLog = $"Last event: OnPageChanged, CurrentPage: {args.CurrentPage}, TotalPages: {args.TotalPages}";
}

_Imports.razor:
@using BlazorBootstrap

Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddScoped<BlazorBootstrap.PdfViewerJsInterop>();


